# How to find translation in any level with Rails I18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

`t some_translation_key` finds only if `some_translation_key` is at first level, that is `en.some_translation_key`. I want a method that will find a translation in any level, that is:

```
en:
  level1:
    level2:
      some_translation_key: 'The translation of some translation key'
```

I still want to access it with `t some_translation_key` without knowing the `level1` or `level2`. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would you differentiate between translations for `level1.level2.some_key` and `level3.level4.some_key`?

What you can do to get concise translation keys is to use it like this: `t '.some_key'`, this will look for the key in `#{controller}.#{view}.some_key`.

For example, if you have this code in `app/views/users/new.html.erb`:

```
<h1><%= t '.title' %></h1>
```

Rails will look for a translation with key `users.new.title`.

See section **4.1.4 "Lazy" Lookup** of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: Thanks, but I basically want to find the first translation string it finds. Basically don't want to put duplicates just because I need to write dynamic code to find translation for example for 'email' or similar.

Comment: If your translation is very generic, then just use a "global" key like "app.email". In my experience, translation can get really hairy if you go with a "dynamic translation" style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strings separated by a dot.

```
t("level1.level2.some_translation_key")
```

Comment: I don't have info about `level1` and `level2` only the end translation string. It's a dynamic thing I'm working with, but thanks for the obvious, maybe it's useful for somebody.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right; so why don't your work with the attributes? Even with activerecord might be a good idea: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Translation.html#method-i-human_attribute_name